# Angular: update a child boolean component from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button in a child component that trigger a loader when it is clicked. And Observable in a parent component where I would like to stop the Loader when the Pdf is loaded

Child component that do:

```
<nsnet-loader *ngIf="pdfLoading"></nsnet-loader>
<button
(click)="triggerLoader()"
[ngClass]="{'is-not-loading': !pdfLoading}"
>
<span>Download</<span>
</button>

export class ButtonDownloadComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() check = false;
  pdfLoading = false;

  triggerLoader() {
   this.pdfLoading = true;
  }

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (this.check) {
    this.pdfLoading = false;
  }
 }
}
```

And the parent component

```
...
<button-download
(click)="getUrl(devis)"
[check]="stopLoader()"
>
</button-download>
...

stopLoader(): boolean {
  return true;
}

getUrl(devis: Devis) {
 
 setTimeout(() => { this.stopLoader() }, 2000)

 this.xxx.subscribe((res: Blob) => {
  // some logics
  this.stopLoader();
 }
}
```

I don't understand why it is not working... The loader is still running

Answer (score 0):

Your parent is subscribing to something.. but what? I don't see a subject or observable in child. Or a `.next()`. Something is amiss here.

In Child, set up a `Subject` to be observed

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class ButtonDownloadComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() check = false;
  pdfLoading = false;
  loaded$ = new Subject<Blob>

  triggerLoader() {
   this.pdfLoading = true;
  }

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (this.check) {
    this.pdfLoading = false;
    loaded$.next(this.res); // you are passing a blob back to parent, so whatever that value is here
  }
 }
}
```

in Parent subscribe to the Subejct and put in an unsubscribe for onDestroy

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

loadedSub: Subscription;

stopLoader(): boolean {
  return true;
}

getUrl(devis: Devis) {
 setTimeout(() => { this.stopLoader() }, 2000)
 loadedSub = this.xxx.subscribe((res: Blob) => {
  // some logics
  this.stopLoader();
 }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   loadedSub.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: @Younes - Did this help solve your question? If so, please accept as the answer. thanks